# Enable parallel query processing in Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Does anyone know how to enable parallel query processing in Azure SQL Database. I'm trying to debug some queries which are running acceptable on my laptop (sql server 2017) but are very slow in azure SQL db. The pricing tier for azure database is Standard S2: 50 DTUs. The only difference I saw in query plan used on my laptop is Distribute Streams, Repartition Streams, and Gather Streams. How can I enable these in azure? I couldn't found any documentation regarding these options in azure database.

**Update**

Since was not able to obtain the same query plan in azure, I checked the number of cpu cores of the azure sql database. It seems that for Standard S2 pricing tier is just one core. To see the number of cores in azure database I used this query: (reference: http://www.nikoport.com/2015/03/19/azure-sqldatabase-v12-premium-editions-and-available-cores/)

```sql
select * from sys.dm_os_schedulers
         where status = 'VISIBLE ONLINE' and is_online = 1
```

On azure I got just one entry, while on my laptop I have 8 cpu cores. If I run the query with OPTION (MAXDOP 1) I got the same execution plan on my machine

Answer (score 4):

SQL Azure has reservation sizes that are (at the low-end) less than a full core and at the high-end contain multiple cores.  There are actually two pricing models right now in SQL Azure:
* Basic/Standard/Premium
* v-Core based

The Basic/Standard/Premium model had more-or-less fixed fractions of CPU, memory, IOPS, and storage.  The v-core based model exposes a bit more of the hardware (you can see the CPU generations and choose which ones you want) and you can purchase storage/iops separately.

You were using an S2 database.  Basic and Standard (up to ~S3) are really only selling you a fraction of a core at those price points.  Premium P1 is about a core, and the v-core model sells you 1 or more cores.

If you want parallel query plans, you need to have a reservation size that is greater than a single core.

Comment: Thank you @Conor! It is tricky to explain to a manager that the S2 database from azure is slowly than my standard development laptop :) What I was not able to find is an official documentation from Microsoft with these information. Of course if I look on the options now and compare the prices with 2 v-Core it is clear that on S3 you cannot have more that one core.

Comment: The premium/standard/basic model was targeted at selling a transaction throughput rate for an OLTP workload.  So, most of the resources were abstracted away as a result.  The new v-core model is more explicit.  One detail:  In the business critical model you are paying for (generally) 4x the core count in SQL Azure vs. a single VM.  This is because you get multiple replicas (different machines) built-in with your database to provide high-availability.  You can look at sys.dm_os_schedulers in any reservation to determine if you have > 1 to enable parallelism or not.

Comment: What about elastic pools? I have a 100eDTU elastic pool (standard). I get parallel plans shown in query analyser. Note: I see two cores when I run the query from the OP.

Comment: Elastic Pools have a total size of the pool and then per-db limits.  Both need to be greater than a core to enable parallel query plans.  You can look at sys.dm_os_schedulers to see how many cores SQL thinks it has for a given reservation size.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism is enabled by default in Azure SQL Database. If you're is not enabled, it's possible that it was disabled through the [ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql) command. Use that same command to enable parallelism.

Comment: Thank you! I checked that settings, default value was 0, I also tried other values, but the execution plan is the same. Is there anything else I could check to see why  parallelism is not used? The database is the same, is a copy from azure.

Comment: What about the cost threshold for parallelism. You can't affect that in Azure. Also, the Azure optimizer is different (not radically, but possibly enough) from the 2017 optimizer. However, I'll be there are more differences than just a parallel vs. a non-parallel plan.

Comment: I missed Conor's answer the first time. It's the correct one. You should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL DB as well SQL Server will decide if your query should run with parallelism.  Parallelism in SQL Server generally has to reach a cost threshold (See CostThresholdForParallelism supported in sql server only).  I have seen queries never run with parallelism enabled.  However, you can force parallelism with a hint.

```sql
OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'))
```